# Apple software version naming convension

Tags: xcode, ios, macos

I downloaded the 2nd GM version of xcode 4 about a week ago, the public release just came out today, is there any difference between the GM and the public version?
Does GM mean RTM or RC?

Comment: wow, at long last ! Not free any more though - $5 in the App Store (unless you're a $99 member).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have a look at the build numbers. GM2 was `4A304a` and the today released version is `4A304a`.

So they are the same.